# How to get my JTable data to update

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am making a simple simulation game where the user buys items, and then sells them on when the price increases in later turns.
I have a JTable that lists the items current price, item type etc, but I have simplified down the code somewhat so it should be easier to look through:

```
public void example()
{
    Object rowData[][] = {             
        { "Item 1", ""+game.getItem1Price()+""},
        { "Item 2", ""+game.getItem2Price()+""},
        { "Item 3", ""+game.getItem3Price()+""}};
         //game.getItem1Price refers to a method in another class that returns the price of Item1


    String[] columnNames = {"Item Name",
                         "Item Price"};

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames) 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            //all cells false
            return false;
        }
    };

    JTable priceTable = new JTable();                     
    priceTable.setModel(tableModel);
    priceTable.setSelectionMode(1);
    priceTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(priceTable);  
    //then add table to frame
}
```

At the end of each turn, the prices are changed and I would like the the table to show the changed price, but I do not know how to get the table update itself.
I have looked online and I have found many methods such as .repaint() but they do not seem to work.

Cheers in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Data in a JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918727/updating-data-in-a-jtable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes you make should be made to the model, the model should then fire notifications back to the table so that the table can be updated

See

- [`DefaultTableModel#setValueAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)
- [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Something along the lines of

```
tableModel.setValueAt(row, column, game.getItem1Price());
```

For example

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want the table to update, you must change the Table Model.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)priceTable.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[] {item1, item2, item3});
```

Once you add to the model, the table will automatically update.